# Excel macro - running through cells on the same level

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, selection

So I want to run through A1-C200 and paste everything into a Word document. The trouble is, I have two ways of pasting it into Word, but each one has its downfall.

**Goal: Copy A1-C200 into Word and keep the column layout, without copying blancs.**

**Example 1:**

The code below copies everything into Word, but runs from A1 -> A200, B1 -> B200, C1 -> C200. Because it reads through my file this way, I lose my column layout. I would prefer a solution for this example, because this code looks clearer to me.

```
iMaxRow = 200

" Loop through columns and rows"
For iCol = 1 To 3
    For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow

    With Worksheets("GreatIdea").Cells(iRow, iCol)
        " Check that cell is not empty."
        If .Value = "" Then
            "Nothing in this cell."
            "Do nothing."
        Else
            " Copy the cell to the destination"
            .Copy
            appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial
        End If
    End With

    Next iRow
Next iCol
```

**Example 2:**

The code below copies the correct column layout, but also inserts blancs. So if A1-A5 and A80-A90 are filled in, I will have 75 blancs in my Word document.

```
a1 = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address
lastcell = Range("C1").Address
Range(a1, lastcell).Copy
With Range("A1") 
Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(2, 3)).Copy
End With
Range("A1:C50").Copy
appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the blanks? Do you want the content of A80-A90 to be shifted up next to A1-A5? Or keep the values already in your Word table so they aren't overwritten by blanks? Assuming it's a Word table? Pls clarify.

Comment: Also your second code example is a real mess! The first 7 lines are mutually redundant; you're copying 3 different ranges and not pasting them anywhere.

Comment: ooh, well example 2 was my first bit of coding. But yes, I want the contents of A80-A90 shifted up so they come under A1-A5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do this, don't know which is the quickest but here's some code I threw together real quick for you. Getting the range all at once in a variant is the fastest way to grab data out of excel.

```
Sub test()

        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim wd As Word.Document
        Dim wdTable As Word.Table
        Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim v1 As Variant
        Set wd = GetObject("C:\Documents and Settings\Jon\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.doc")

'Get data in array
        Set wks = ActiveSheet
        v1 = wks.UsedRange        

'Create table
        Set wdTable = wd.Tables.Add(Range:=wd.Application.Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
            ubound(v1,2), DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
            wdAutoFitFixed)


        'Place data
        For i = 1 To UBound(v1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(v1, 2)
                If Len(v1(i, j)) > 0 Then
                    'Add row if not enough rows, this can be done before the j loop if
                    'you know the first column is always filled.
                    'You can also do an advanced filter in excel if you know that the first
                    'column is filled always and filter for filled cells then just
                    'do a straight copy and paste using r1.specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy 
                    'If you know the rows ahead of time when you create the table you can create all the rows at once,
                     'which should save time.
                    wd.application.selection
                    If wdTable.Rows.Count < i Then wdTable.Rows.Add
                    wdTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = v1(i, j)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        Set wks = Nothing: Set wd = Nothing: Set v1 = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this gives an error on application.selection.

Comment: Did you just copy and paste my code or use it with yours? If you used it with yours you might have wd as word.application, in which case you wouldn't need wd.application.selection you would just need wd.selection.

Comment: I copied your entire code, and it still gives an error. But i think it's cause I don't select or copy anything? I presume where all your comments are, I need to add some selection or copy?

Comment: Did you reference this "C:\Documents and Settings\Jon\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.doc" or your own document?

Comment: The range from the worksheet just grabs the active worksheet (the last worksheet you had open. The Excel document must be open. The word document is either opened or grabbed by the program by the getobject. I don't work with word very often so I'm not quite sure why it wouldn't be working correctly on that side, it did work for me though. The range for the placement of the table was grabbed from whatever was selected. You could have your file already open and test to see if you need to just have some part of word selected. I wouldn't think you would need to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure I understand the prob ... but here's a stab at it:

```
dim rg200x3 as range: set rg200x3 = range("a1:c200")

dim Col1 as new collection
dim Col2 as new collection
dim Col3 as new collection

dim rgRow as new range
dim sText as string
for each rgRow in rg200x3
    sText = trim(rgRow.cells(1,1)): if (sText <> "") call Col1.Add(sText)
    sText = trim(rgRow.cells(1,2)): if (sText <> "") call Col2.Add(sText)
    sText = trim(rgRow.cells(1,3)): if (sText <> "") call Col3.Add(sText)
next rgRow
```

at this point Col1, Col2, and Col3 contain your text w the blank cells factored out, so now loop over these to print out

```
dim i as long
for i = 1 to 200
    on error resume next  ' (cheap way to avoid checking if index > collection sz)
    debug.print Col1(i) + " | " Col2(i) + " | " + Col3(i)
    on error goto 0
next i
```

(note: code typed in freehand with no checking ... )

Comment: But how do I copy it into Word?

Answer (score 0):

How about this to sub for your first solution:

```
iMaxRow = 200

" Loop through columns and rows"
For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow
  For iCol = 1 To 3

    With Worksheets("GreatIdea").Cells(iRow, iCol)
      " Check that cell is not empty."
      If .Value = "" Then
          "Nothing in this cell."
          "Do nothing."
      Else
           "Copy the cell to the destination"
          .Copy appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial
      End If
    End With

  Next iCol
Next iRow
```

Comment: @Tom, No that was just formatting.  All I did was switch Row to be the outside loop, and Column to be the inside loop.